# T4 Template throws error when inserting a control block

Tags: c#, t4

I am using the following line in a text template file

```
 <SettingsFilePath>
 <#=GetParameterValue("Blah")#>\Deploy\Settings\DeploymentSetting_<#environment.Name#>_<#=workflow.Name#>.xml
 </SettingsFilePath>
```

When I try to modify this line to insert another expression (`environment.Type.ToString()`) as follows

```
<SettingsFilePath>
<#=GetParameterValue("Blah")#>\Deploy\Settings\<#=environment.Type.ToString()#>\DeploymentSetting_<#environment.Name#>_<#=workflow.Name#>.xml
</SettingsFilePath>
```

I get the following error in Visual Studio compilation of TT Templates

> An unexpected start or end tag was found within a block. Make sure that you did not mis-type a start or end tag, and that you do not have any nested blocks in the template.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? All the `<#= #>` blocks are properly matched.

Comment: I think the \ is being taken for an escape. Try just using string.Format for all of it.

Comment: You have `<#environment.Name#>`; change it to `<#=environment.Name#>` if you want to print it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I worked around it by using String.format as per Aaron's suggestion

```
<SettingsFilePath><#=string.Format(@"{0}\Deploy\Settings\{1}\DeploymentSetting_{2}_{3}.xml",GetParameterValue("blah"),environment.Type.ToString(), environment.Name, workflow.Name)#></SettingsFilePath>
```